# I want to disable the next button when form showing last record and disble the previous button when form showing first record

Tags: html, typescript

```js
mortgage_items: GetMtgMortgageMasterForView[];  
  CurrentRecordIndex: number;
  
   onClicknext(): void {
  if (this.CurrentRecordIndex < this.mortgage_items.length - 1)
  {
   //increment only if current index is less than length - 1
   this.CurrentRecordIndex = this.CurrentRecordIndex + 1;
   this.showData();
   
  }

   }

   onClickprevious(): void{
  if (this.CurrentRecordIndex >0)
  {
   //decrement only if current index is more than 0
   this.CurrentRecordIndex = this.CurrentRecordIndex - 1;
   this.showData();   
  }

   }
```

```html
 <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class=" col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Customer Zip</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" id="customerZipFilter" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="customerZipFilter" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="colFormLabelSm" class=" col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Expiration Date</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" id="maxExpirationDateFilter" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="maxExpirationDateFilter" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
              </div>
            </div>
            
 <button class="btn btn-primary blue" (click)="onClickprevious()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>Previous</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger red" [disabled]="statusId == 3 || statusId == 4 " (click)="onClickreject()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Reject</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info metal" [disabled]="statusId == 3 || statusId == 4 " (click)="onClicksave()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save </button>
    <button class="btn btn-success green" [disabled]="statusId == 3 || statusId == 4 " (click)="onClicksubmit()"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary blue"(click)="onClicknext()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Next</button>
```

I have records in my DB.and Data also showing on fields and next and previous buttons are for fetching the records one by one.but i want to disable the next and previous buttons to disable when there is first and last record and and i have the data trasfer object as  mortgage_items which having all the records in DB.

Comment: Show us what you've tried for achieving this, so we can help you.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to implement some kind of pagination. for this you need to keep track of index of item currently being displayed. and based on that you can disable previous and next button. if you stuck at some point please share your code so that we can debug.

Comment: i will explain the code